# Move or copy a file from the request to multiple locations

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel and taking in input and file uploads. This page takes changes that users want to make to an order. The end goal is to take this input and apply it to multiple orders.

I can reuse the input for each of the orders. But what would be a good way for me to copy that file in the request to multiple directories? For example, as in the documentation, I originally have: `$request->file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);` which works fine for one order. But now that I want to apply it to many orders, I can't move that same file from the request anymore since it doesn't exist.

And it looks like the UploadedFile object doesn't have a `copy()` method. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not depend on component too much. Keep it simple

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destination_path, $file_name);

//Add DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR between path and filename if needed
copy($destination_path.$file_name, $new_path.$new_file_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may make a suggestion assuming these files are going to stay the same (you aren't allowing your users to modify these files by order), I think it makes sense to store one copy of the file on the server and use a database table to determine which orders that file belongs to and manage it all in the table.  You may need to create a `files` table and an `file_order` table and give it a many to many relationship to your `orders` table but in the end, if these files are allowed to be large, could save you a lot of space and in my opinion, make it easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, look at the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php` , and I hope you'll get the everything of file, how they manage the files.

How to ***copy a file***, ***move a file***, ***delete a file*** everything is described clearly in that.

For copy a file in Laravel, there function is:

```
/**
 * Copy a file to a new location.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string  $target
 * @return bool
 */
public function copy($path, $target)
{
    return copy($path, $target);
}
```

I think there's nothing to say now.
Just use that

```
File::copy('file_name_with_full_path', 'target_directory_where_copy');
```

Hope, it might be helpful for you.