# Laravel: The file was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: php, file, upload, laravel-5.3

I am trying to upload a file to two different locations. The lcoations being `/2x/` adn `/3x/`. It uploads the file on 3x but doesn't on 2x and throws this error:

> The file was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Here is what i am doing:

```
$photo = $request->file('photo');

    if (isset($photo)) {
        if ($photo != null || $photo != '') {

            $imageSize = getimagesize($photo);
            $resolution = $imageSize[0] . 'x' . $imageSize[1];

            if ($resolution == '300x300' || $resolution == '450x450') {

                if (!file_exists(base_path('uploads/custom_avatar'))) {
                    mkdir(base_path('uploads/custom_avatar'), 0777, true);
                }

                $resolution = "3x";

                $uploadPath = base_path('uploads/custom_avatar/' . $resolution . '/');

                $otherImageResolution = '2x';
                $otherImagePath = base_path('uploads/custom_avatar/' . $otherImageResolution . '/');
                //echo $otherImagePath;exit;
                // saving image
                $fileName = $child->id . '_' . time() . '.png';

                $photo->move($uploadPath, $fileName);
                $photo->move($otherImagePath, $fileName);

                // creating records
                $childImage = Images::addPhoto($child->id, $fileName, $resolution);
                $otherImage = Images::addPhoto($child->id, $fileName, $otherImageResolution);

                if ($childImage && $otherImage) {
                    $result = Child::createChildResponseData($child);
                    \Log::info('Child avatar added Successfully' . json_encode($childImage));
                    return response()->json([
                        'status' => $this->SUCCESS,
                        'response' => $result,
                    ], $this->SUCCESS);
                }
```

Any help?

Comment: Move or copy a file from the request to multiple locations [stackoverflow question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979386/move-or-copy-a-file-from-the-request-to-multiple-locations)

Comment: Thankyou @SurenderSinghRawat, It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$request->file('photo')->move($destination_path, $file_name);
```

Add DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR between path and filename if needed and
copy that file at new location

```
copy($destination_path.$file_name, $new_path.$new_file_name);
```

Answer (score 25):

Check your code if your file upload code is running two times.

I was facing the same issue & then I find that my file upload code is running two times.

after commenting one of them it's working fine.

Comment: you are right, my file upload was running two times.

Comment: also i am faced to this issue and it's uploading two times in foreach. thank you for idea and it's worked

Comment: It worked for me as i looked into my foreach, i was uploading same file twice, resulting in error. your hint solved my problem. thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was uploading it twice, using same name for different files, thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks. I checked and when i was uploading 2 files i for error moved 2 times the same one :)

Comment: oopss... you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Check your code if your file upload code is running two times.
You can check this part of the code. Make sure you type it correctly and not repeat it twice.

```
   // Original size upload file
    $section_image_file->move($folder, $section_image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you call any method (like $file->getSize()), because it calls the move method too.