# Why I'm getting unknown error while uploading a csv file in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

While uploading CSV file in laravel, am getting the error saying

> "Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileException
>   The file "DealProducts.csv" was not uploaded due to an unknown error".

```
 $folder = 'owner';
 $path1 = base_path('resources/importedfiles/' . $folder . '/');
 File::makeDirectory($path1, 0777, true, true);
 $file = request()->file('file_name');
 $fileName = md5($file->getClientOriginalName()) . '_' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.csv';
 $uploadingPath = asset('resources/importedfiles/' . $folder . '/');
     if ($file->move($path1, $fileName)) {
        $offers = $request->get('offers');
        ImportFile::create([
          'file_name' => $fileName,
             'file_size' => round($file->getClientSize() / (1024 * 1024), 2),
             'offer_id'  => $offers,
           ]);

     }
 return redirect('/admin/importfiles');
```

Comment: You're creating an `$uploadingPath`, but you're not using it. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964907/laravel-the-file-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the php.ini file, change the following

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

This may help.