# Laravel 5.4 file uploading error - fileName not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: laravel, image, file, upload

Im trying to upload multiple images to via below code in laravel. In my form there are 3 types of images to be selected to upload. When user select all the images and then submit the form. I need to upload all the images to same folder . First images get uploaded in to the folder. But then it gives me below error.

> The file "1575738164-main-slider2.webp" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.

Controller

```
  if ($request->hasFile('image') &&  $request->hasFile('image_575') && $request->hasFile('image_768')){

        $file = $request->image;
        $file_575 = $request->image_575;
        $file_768 = $request->image_768;

        $name = time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $name_575 = time().'-'.$file_575->getClientOriginalName();
        $name_768 = time().'-'.$file_768->getClientOriginalName();

        $names = [ $name , $name_575 , $name_768];

        foreach ( $names as $n){

            $file->move('uploads/banners/',$n);   
        }

        $banner = new Banner();
        $banner->name = $name;
        $banner->name_575 = $name_575;
        $banner->name_768 = $name_768;

        $banner -> side_color = $request -> side_color ;
        $banner->type = $request->type;
        $banner->save();
    }
```

Please note that I have almost gone through below questions.
[Laravel: The file was not uploaded due to an unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964907/laravel-the-file-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First only using `time()` method won't work to generate unique file name for all three images all the time and when a concurrent request occurs.

Second:

```
    $names = [ $name , $name_575 , $name_768];

    foreach ( $names as $n){

        $file->move('uploads/banners/',$n);   
    }
```

What you are looping is totally wrong. You are trying to move the same image, $file for three times.

You have to move all the three images inside the loop:
`

```
    $file = $request->image;
    $file_575 = $request->image_575;
    $file_768 = $request->image_768;
```

`

So, you should probably do:

```
 $filesToMoves = [$name=> $file, $name_575 => $file2 , $name_768 => $file3];

foreach($filesToMoves as $fileName => $fileToMove){
        $fileToMove->move('uploads/banners/',$fileName);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I know files wont be samed in names. However Im having a new error `Illegal offset type` now

Comment: I have updated my answer please check. I forgot to change the $file in the loop to $fileToMove

Comment: Also on the $request make sure that you are receiving image, image_575 and image_768

Comment: Thanks yes they are receving via request. I have changed your code with `$ name_768` but still it generate error iIllegal offset type

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Looks like the array I build was incorrect, I made the class object as the array index so it was throwing Illegal offset type. 
I have changed the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AnujShrestha

Answer (score 0):

I will add my code for future references that I used to solve this issue

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this -> validate ( request () , [
        'image' => 'required|mimes:webp|dimensions:max_width=1200,max_height=380|max:50' ,
        'image_575' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|dimensions:max_width=575,max_height=380|max:80' ,
        'image_768' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|dimensions:max_width=768,max_height=380|max:80' ,
    ] ) ;

    if ($request->hasFile('image') &&  $request->hasFile('image_575') && $request->hasFile('image_768')){

        $fils = [$request->image, $request->image_575, $request->image_768];
        $formats = ['webp' , '575','768'];
        $fileNames = [];
        $i = 0;
            foreach($fils as $file){
                    $name = time().'_'.$formats[$i].'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $file->move('uploads/banners/', $name);
                    array_push($fileNames, $name);
                    $i++;
            }

        $a= new X();
        $a->name = $fileNames[0];
        $a->image_575 = $fileNames[1];
        $a->image_768 = $fileNames[2];

        $a->save();
    }
```

This is just for information.