# Laravel I try to duplicate an object and add pictures in each object

Tags: laravel

I have a room to add. And there are fields called pieces. If the user has written all the fields, he chose pictures for the room. and wrote 5 pieces. I want to add 5 pieces to the same room with selected fields and photos. That is, duplicate the same object in several pieces.

RoomController store function

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title.*' => 'required',
            'content.*' => 'required',
            'people' => 'required',
            'hotel_id' => 'required',
            'night_price' => 'required',
            'pieces' => 'required',
            'single_bed' => 'required',
            'double_bed' => 'required',
            'roomImages' => 'required',
            'roomImages.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
        ]);

        $rooms = array_fill(1, $request->get('pieces'), $request->all());
        foreach ($rooms as $room){
            dd($rooms);
            $obj = new Room();
            // Set translations
            $obj->setTranslations('title', $room['title']);
            $obj->setTranslations('content', $room['content']);

            // Save object
            $obj->amenities = $room['amenities'];
            $obj->fill($room);
            $obj->save();

            foreach ($room['roomImages'] as $file) {
                $file_name = time() . '_' . md5($file->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file->move(public_path('/uploads/rooms/'), $file_name);
                // Save image in Model Image
                $file = new Image();
                $file->src = $file_name;
                $obj->file()->save($file);
            }
        }


        return redirect()->route('rooms.index');
    }
```

Error
[image]

One circle of the foreach is running, the object with the pictures is added. On the 2nd lap, the foreach stops and shows this error

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45208208/7574023) could be useful for you

Comment: I have a different situation. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: can you create public git repository and share??

Comment: This project is my first order. I don’t think the client would like it if I expose it publicly. Tell me which part of the code you need, I'll show you.

Comment: it might help to see your database structure and see why some of those need to be duplicated

Comment: Because there are rooms that are the same, only a few of them. And the client can reserve several rooms at once.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/ARMCODE/kesminta.com/src/master/

Comment: Here are the repositories. Please help me figure out the problem

Comment: You shouldn't be uploading your code if this is a paid project (where you may like;y be under a NDA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the bellow code

```
foreach ($request->roomImages as $file) {
    $file_name = time() . '_' . md5($file->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->move(public_path('/uploads/rooms/'), $file_name);
}

$rooms = array_fill(1, $request->get('pieces'), $request->all());
foreach ($rooms as $key => $room){
    $obj = new Room();
    // Set translations
    $obj->setTranslations('title', $room['title']);
    $obj->setTranslations('content', $room['content']);

    // Save object
    $obj->amenities = $room['amenities'];
    $obj->fill($room);
    $obj->save();


    \File::copy(public_path('/uploads/rooms/'.$file_name), public_path('/uploads/rooms/'.$key.$file_name));

    $file = new Image();
    $file->src = $key.$file_name;

    $obj->file()->save($file);
}
\File::delete(public_path('/uploads/rooms/'.$file_name));
```

The move function will delete the file from the original request. So when the loop run second time, you are getting error.

Comment: Your example images are added once. my goal each room in the loop has its own images and adds them .

Comment: Thank you, very help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

So your issue looks like you are overriding `$file` when creating your Image model.

```
foreach ($room['roomImages'] as $file) {
    $file_name = time() . '_' . md5($file->getClientOriginalName()) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->move(public_path('/uploads/rooms/'), $file_name);
    // Save image in Model Image
    // Updated variable name
    $image = new Image();
    $image->src = $file_name;
    // save Model
    $image->save();
    $obj->file()->save($file);
}
```