# Store Multiple Data From Api in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, postman

```
public function saveOrder(Request $request)
{
    $sid = explode(",", $request->subcat_id);
    $quan = explode(",", $request->quantity);
    $amnt = explode(",", $request->amount);
    $c = count($sid);
    
    for($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) {
        $order = new Order();
        $order->quantity = $quan[$i];
        $order->amount = $amnt[$i];
        $order->subcat_id = $sid[$i];
        $order->address = $request->address;
        $order->payment_mode = $request->payment_mode;
        $order->order_no = $this->generateOrderNR();
        
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            echo "in".$i;
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $file_name = time() . rand(1, 999) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move(base_path('images/orders/'), $file_name);
            $order->image = $file_name;

        }
        
        if ($order->save()) {
            echo "Order";
            //return response()->json(['status' => 200, 'msg' => 'Order Placed Successfully']);
        } else
            echo "Error";
            //return response()->json(['status' => 200, 'msg' => 'Error Occured']);
    }
}
```

> in0 Order in1{
> "message": "The file "277762619_112136134785398_1736805384468006822_n.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error."

Why this is error is coming up every time, because of this error in database only 1 row is saved and another row isn't saved when is send data like this in postman through api:-

```
address: Lucknow,
quantity: 1,1,
amount: 150,162,
payment_mode: CASH,
subcat_id: 8,12
```

Comment: error is not about database its about image upload

Comment: I searched for your error and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964907/laravel-the-file-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error).  The answers suggest your file upload code is running twice.  Looking again at your code, yes it is - even if you have 2x `$sid`, so you are creating 2x `Order`s, your file upload code only works for 1 file: `$request->file('image')`.  So it will be processed for the first iteration, and then the same file will be processed again for the 2nd iteration.  That throws the error. You either need to process a different file, or do it only once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: The file was not uploaded due to an unknown error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964907/laravel-the-file-was-not-uploaded-due-to-an-unknown-error)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes image insertion goes 2 times when there is only one image comes from api. And when i save only one order everything works fine but more than 1 order creation this error thrown and this didn't solve from your given answer. I think maybe i need to send more than 1 image or i need to check first how many images are there

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I said: "*You either need to process a different file, or do it only once.*" If you are allowing multiple Orders in one submission, you either need to allow multiple files on your form, *or* process just one, ie set a flag when you have processed it and don't do it again on the next iteration.  The issue is the same as the duplicate :-)

Answer (score 0):

The second file you wanna upload is too big maybe.
Please check `php.ini` if the file size exceeds the `upload_max_filesize`.
Then, increase the size like `1000M` or something.
Then restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loop you can pass an array in the insert or create method. Check below code sample :

```
AppSettings::insert([
    [
        'name'=>'mail_host',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',

    ],
    [
        'name'=>'mail_port',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',

    ],
    [
        'name'=>'mail_username',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead move()

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$file_name = time().rand(1, 999).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
File::copy($file->getPathname(), base_path('images/orders/'.$file_name));
```